# How to show login page first before home page using spring security?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I need to show login page before home page. If username and password is correct for user then I need to move to home page. But in this program home page is displayed first and when I type '/login' then only login page is shown. 
How can I first show login page and after authentication of user, home page need to be shown?

This is my code in Security configuration class. I have skipped other part as only from here program is handled.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/home").access("hasRole('User')")
        .and()
        .formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
        .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied");
    }
```

And this is my controller class

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage(ModelMap model,
            @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout,
            @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error) {

        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/","/home"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String homePage(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hi, Welcome to mysite");
        return "welcome";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/accessDenied", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage() {
        return "accessDenied";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're accessing the home page under the URL `/`. The requirement to be logged in is only applied to `/home`:

```
.antMatchers("/home").access("hasRole('User')")
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to change the url from http://localhost:8080/SpringProject1/ to http://localhost:8080/SpringProject1/login at the start of spring application using security? I am getting http://localhost:8080/SpringProject1/ always at the beginning of application.